# change to polar coordinates in a ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I don't know what to do.

> write the following system into polar coordinates
>
> $$x'=-ay$$
> $$y'=ax$$
>
> with $a\in \mathbb R$

any idea?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\cost}{\cos\theta} \newcommand{\sint}{\sin\theta}$
Let $(x,y) = (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$. Then,
$$
\begin{align}
x' &= r'\cost - r\theta'\sint = -ar\sint\\
x' &= r'\sint + r\theta'\cos = ar\cost
\end{align}
$$
In a matrix form,

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cost & -r\sint\\
\sint & r\cost
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
r'\\ \theta'
\end{bmatrix}
=
ar
\begin{bmatrix}
-\sint\\
\cost
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I think you know what to do after this.

You will get finally, $r' = 0$ and $\theta' = a$, which means that the solution of the ODE draws a circle of radius $r(0)$ with the angular velocity $a$.

Comment: @Moo We don't need to use the equation as I demonstrated in the answer. Do you know how to get the inverse of a matrix?